# WPF Datagrid add button to datarowheader

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid. I am trying to add a toggle button to the datarowheader with a triangle shape. The shape should point to the right and then once click show the row details and the arrow should point down.

```
 <!-- The data grid to display orders-->
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}" 
                  x:Name="dataGridOrders" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
                  Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}"                      
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader}"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}"                      
                  RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource DG_RowDetail}"                      
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Silver"
                  RowHeaderWidth="30"                      
                  Margin="25,5,20,15"> 


<!-- Data Grid row header template -->
    <Style x:Key="DG_RowHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGRH_Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightGray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>                        
                </ControlTemplate>                         
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="M"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: how to add a toggle button to a row in a datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a control Template that has a toggle button something like this for the Row Header:

```
    <Style x:Key="DG_RowHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <ToggleButton Content="button" x:Name="btn"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="btn" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="btn" Value="-"/>
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="False">
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="btn" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="btn" Value="+"/>
                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Uma that does indeed work. The only slight issue I have is where to put the border that was originally in my DG_RowHeader style? as the LinearGradientBrush is now not applied.

Comment: Toggle Button can be placed inside the Border, you will have to make the background of the Toggle Button Transparent to be able to see the border.background. Another option is - set the ToggleButton's Background directly with the LinearGradientBrush instead of using a Border.