# Hierarchial Datagrids in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a hierarchical Data grid.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgList" ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sub System" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Name="dgList2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Name1}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="250" Header="Name3" Binding="{Binding Path=Name3}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DataGrid Name="List2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding List3}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="250" Header="FN" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="250" Header="LN" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

The grid works fine,Clicking on the row would expand the sublist. But is it possible to have an arrow or + plus on the left column which would indicate that there are more rows.

Comment: Try to create a DataGridTemplateColumn on Outer DataGrid. Mention Cell Template as a Button with Content = "+" and in the Click Event show your inner DataGrid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473448/togglebutton-changing-image-depending-on-state can be your starting point.